# How to translate "hump" or "humping"?

Tags: translation

I hope this isn't inappropriate, but neither of my two dictionaries had a proper translation. The closest one was `性交`, but to my understanding, that's the same meaning as `上床`. I'm looking for a word that will describe the physical action, whether sexual or not. For example

> He celebrated by humping the air
>
> The guy at the club kept humping my leg on the dance floor.

Answer (score 1):

**thrust** as in *hip thrust* is often translated as:

> 冲刺

Hip thrust for instance can be translated as 臀部冲刺. A movement that is pretty similar to the “humping the air”.

Dog humping their owners can be translated as 爬. Which might be more appropriate for the guy at the club.

Comment: How would you use 爬 in the second sentence?

Comment: I don't think 爬 is the correct word to be use, althought I do not have a better suggestion.  爬 will be an action of climbing up the leg instead of humping the leg.  However, the description on a movement of hip thrust does fit well

Answer (score -2):

What're you doing, translating erotic stories? How about 抽插？

The guy at the club kept humping my leg on the dance floor.

在俱乐部舞池的地板上那个家伙不停地在我脚上抽插着。

A slap in the face is called for!